# Зачем нужны структуры , если есть объединения?

Tags: c, структуры

Зачем нужны структуры , если есть объединения?
Изучаю Си , изучил структуры , понял , что это набор типов данных. Потом дошёл до объединений , как я понял, их используют для экономии памяти. В таком случае зачем вообще использовать структуры?
Объясните, пожалуйста, когда и где лучше использовать структуры и объединения.

Comment: Вы точно разобрались, что такое объединения? Они работают совершенно иначе и не могут быть использованы как замена структурам

Comment: Покажите, как вы замените объединением `struct Point { int x,  y; }`. Что-то непонятна ваша идея...

Comment: Не разобрался , поэтому и спрашиваю. Когда используют структуры , а когда обьявления ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Когда нужно объединение (не в смысле `union`, в смысле логическом) разных данных в единое целое с возможностью **одновременного** доступа к разным данным - это структура (`struct`).
Когда очень надо сэкономить память, и при этом одновременного обращения к разным типам гарантированно не будет - объединение (`union`).